# ImaginePlugin for CakePHP and Mac

Tags: macos, cakephp, plugins

to maintain picture uploads in our current project, i decided to use the ImaginePlugin for CakePHP from https://github.com/CakeDC/Imagine

For me everything worked fine, so i comitted the code to our SVN and my fellow-worker updated it to test it.

But he's now getting everywhere "class not found" errors like this one

```
Class 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine' not found in ...
```

I'm working on a Windows Machine, he's working on a Mac.
anyone experienced that before too? is there a problem with the directory seperators?
is the plugin only working for windows machines?

or are we doing some mistakes?

thanks for help

nahri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple

```
$name = str_replace("\\", '/', $name);
```

in the autoloader fixed the problem.

Comment: Or it could be something simpler =)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the CakeDC/Imagine source in your repo? Perhaps it is installed as a submodule? If it isn't in your repo he needs to get it. If it is a submodule perhaps he needs to pull the submodule.